# Right cone, you are at A and need to complete a revolution before reaching the bottom B. What is shortest distance AB?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

You are on a mountain that is a right cone shape. You are trying to get to B and you are somewhere up the mountain A such that you lie on the line OB.

The line AB must do one full revolution of the mountain and is the shortest distance.

What is the general formula for finding any AB distance? How much of that distance is uphill/downhill?

[image]

---

When uncurled the cone looks like the shape below with A and B demonstrated. With A being a distance $x$ along the line OB. I appreciate that the straight line is the shortest distance but how do I work that distance out?

I am not sure where to begin with uphill/downhill part.

[image]

Comment: Not sure how easy the calculation is, but you could calculate the position depending on the height and angle, and then parametrize the path, you could calculate the length of that curve

Comment: I feel like the title is giving me instructions as though I am the cone. "All right, cone, you are at A..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Henry has answered most of your questions, except how to calculate the distance of the path. To find the distance you need to find the angle $\theta$ of the circular sector.

[image]

We know the circular arc of the sector has the same length as the circumference of the cone's base circle, so $\theta s = 2\pi r$ giving: $$\theta = \frac{2 \pi r}{s}$$
If the point $A$ is located a distance $d$ from the cone vertex, we can now use the Law of Cosines to find the path distance x: $$x^2 = s^2 + d^2 - 2sd \cos(\frac{2 \pi r}{s})$$

**EDIT**

To find the uphill distance $x_u$ we use the method given by Henry, i.e. drop a perpendicular from $O$ to $AB$, meeting at $C$. The height $h$ of $OC$ can be found by the area formulas for a triangle: $$\text{Area} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot s \cdot d \cdot \sin(\theta) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot x \cdot h$$
giving $$h = \frac{s \cdot d \cdot \sin(\theta)}{x}$$
We then see that $x_u^2+h^2=d^2$ or $$x_u = \sqrt{d^2-h^2}$$

Comment: The point on line AB where up and down change is the foot point of the height of the triangle.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Cut along the dotted line $OB$, allowing the cone to be flattened.  The quickest winding route $AB$ is then a straight line. *(Added)* to find the uphill part, drop a perpendicular from $O$ to $AB$, meeting at $C$.  On $AC$ the path is approaching $O$ and so uphill,while on $CB$ it is moving away from $O$ and so downhill

[image]
[image]
But if the angle is too big, that straight line would be outside the cone, so the alternative would be to go from $A$ to $O$, round the cone at $O$ and then down to $B$

[image]

Comment: the example I have is of the first depiction. I will copy that image and show in OP.

Comment: If you read the question post, you will see that this is exactly what the OP has already done. The question is about calculating the distance AB in your first figure, and telling which parts of the path are uphill and which are downhill.

Comment: @Arthur between my answer and your comment, the original post was edited to to include my diagram.  I will add a further hint on uphill in the first case

Comment: To include your diagram, sure. But not the idea of "opening" the cone. That was there from the start.

Comment: @Henry thanks for the help managed to solve it from your hints, especially needed the uphill one. +1.

Answer (score 0):

One might solve this numerically using a path of *n* steps.
Let *a* be the direct distance from the cone peak of point A.
 Then the minimal distance between *A* and *B* is given by
the solution of
[image]

Components *x[i]* give the path from *B* to *A* which might get up and down.

Comment: Indeed, when n goes to infinity the solution coincides with the formula given in another answer here. So, both seem correct.

Answer (score 0):

Is there not still an issue with the case where the sector angle is greater than 180 deg, as the solution given does not strictly go around the cone.

I came to this problem via the 'Korean' exam question, where the problem said that it was a sight seeing tour around a mountain and you had to 'go around the mountain'.

Can anyone shed any further light on this?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).